# How to calculate required energy to displace a pendulum?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy, oscillators, displacement

How can one calculate the amount of energy needed to displace pendulum with given mass **m** and string length **L** to $\alpha$ degrees from resting position when acceleration due to gravity is known?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By considering the variation in the potential energy $V=mg\Delta y$ due to the vertical displacement $\Delta y$.

A displacement of an angle $\alpha$ would move the mass of the pendulum horizontally by $\Delta x=L \sin\alpha$ and vertically by $\Delta y=L(1- \cos\alpha)$.

Therefore the energy required for a displacement of an angle $\alpha$ amounts to $mgL( 1-\cos\alpha)$.

If the pendulum is a bar or more generally an object of any shape, of course, you replace L by the distance from the pivot to the centre of mass.

Comment: Here $ g$ is the gravitational acceleration